# changing a c program to a c++ program - compile errors

Tags: c++, c, opencv, rabbitmq

I'm using the [RabbitMQ C library](https://github.com/alanxz/rabbitmq-c). It is written in C and uses CMake. I'm using the basic amqp_sendstring client example. My question is that I need to integrate some c++ code to take pictures using opencv. Is it possible or even recommended to change the example client to `.cpp` files and include my c++ code. I've tried already and I'm getting lots of compile errors.

Comment: If it's an *example client*, sure, go on and port it to C++ if you need. It's a different language, so this will be some work. Don't attempt to convert the *library* though. This would be a much better question if you included your C++ code, showing where exactly you're running into problems.

Comment: Off topic? Really?

Answer (score 1):

You can compile your code with g++, importing your C library as extern "C" {}.

The opposite, that is, importing C++ code to your C code and compiling it with gcc could be quite hard, even impossible, because your C++ libraries could contain specific C++ stuff, such as class, templates, etc...

Comment: And the C library can contain C specific stuff. It's unlikely to work too well in either direction.

Comment: Obviously, the perfect solution is C containing C code, but as I understood, the question was to include C code into C++ code, which is possible (even common, like testing your C code with gtest tools). However the other way (C++ in C), is a chimera.